# Can Entity Framework Core 2 return array or List of int from stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure that returns an array or list of integers using Entity Framework Core 2?

For example I usually would call;

```
context.<entities>.FromSql("proc", "params");
```

However, this would map directly to the core entity which would throw an error as it would not be able to map non-nullable fields.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not supported as of now. There is already an open issue for this, you can track it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8127).